# Click to submit button disable then form Submit working on firefox but not on chrome & safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When Submit form my submit button disable and then form submited its my functionality but its not working on Chrome & Safari

This class used for submit button => SubmitToDisable

```
$('.SubmitToDisable').live('click', function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled',true).addClass('disableButton');
});
```

Comment: which jquery version you are using .live() is depriciated now??..

Comment: Instead of `live` use `on`, its deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9

Comment: jquery version 1.7.2

Comment: use 'on' instead of 'live'

Comment: Firefox make submit button disable then submiting form but Chrome make submit button disable but not form submit

Comment: @avinash post your relevant html part too.

Answer (score 0):

Try as, As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

```
 $('.SubmitToDisable').on('click', function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled','disabled').addClass('disableButton');
 });
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Form Not submited on Chrome

Comment: Functionality -> User cannot click multiple times on submit button so when click on submit button it should be disable and after submit form its commming into enable state. Its working on Firefox but not on Chrome

Comment: So on success you need to use as ` $('.SubmitToDisable').removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: But in Chrome first submit disable. How can I form submit ?

Answer (score 0):

GOT SOLUTION

```
$('.SubmitToDisable').live('click', function(){
            $('form').submit(function(){
                $('.SubmitToDisable').prop('disabled',true).addClass('disableButton');
            });
});
```